# Is there a way I can open the calendar app from the date time widget?

Tags: gnome, calendar

There is a datetime widget that displays in the top center of the ubuntu gnome desktop.

When I click on it, it displays a small calendar. Is there a way I can launch to fullsize calendar app from this datetime widget?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, answers that disappoint do not appear on this site. As answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526980/460708), this is currently not possible/implemented. Gnome Developpers do not want to implement this for now [because there is no common way to open an event in a calendar app](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/262#note_540721).